# Calculate circle segment as proportion of total circle area

Tags: geometry, circles

How can I find the height of the arced portion of a circular segment (['h' in this link](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularSegment.html)) when I only know the radius of the circle and the area of the segment.

The link above gives me an equation for calculating the area of the segment. So I can set this to fraction of the total circle, 'f'.

$$f\pi r^2 = r^2 cos^{-1} \left(\frac{r-h}{r}\right)-(r-h)\sqrt{2rh-h^{2}} $$

I would then need to solve this for 'h', which I'm struggling to do.

I have also tried [using the angle instead](https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/circle-sector-segment.html), which gives a simpler equation. I set the area to the proportion of the total area again.

$$f\pi r^2 = \left(\frac{\theta\pi}{360} - \frac{\sin(\theta)}{2}\right)r^{2}$$

But I have not managed to solve this for $\theta$ either. Ultimately, I want to be able to mark out segments on a circle that correspond with specific proportions of the circle, and need to know where to place the markers. In this particular case the circle has a radius of 23.5mm and the segment's area is $\frac{3}{8}$ of the total circle area.

Comment: This post may help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2619158/can-anyone-rearrange-this-equation-for-the-area-of-a-segment?rq=1. I don't think it will be possible to get an exact answer for h.

Comment: For simplicity put $r=1$ and resort to numerical solution by Runge-Kutta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating it.
Since the ratio $f$ of sector area to circle area always equals the ratio of $θ$ to 2π radians, we have:

$θ = 2\pi f$ in radians or $360^\circ\cdot f$ in degrees.

If we bisect $θ$, we have two right triangles, the hypotenuse being $R$, and the height, $r$. We want to find $r$ since $h + r = R$. We know that $\cos(θ/2) = r/R$ by definition, so:

$r = R\cos(θ/2)$.

Therefore:

$h = R - r$,

$= R - R\cos(θ/2)$,

$= R\,( 1- \cos(\pi f) )$ in radians,

or $R\,(1-\cos(180^\circ\cdot f)$ in degrees.

For $f = \frac{3}{8}$ and $R = 23.5\,\text{mm}$, $h = 14.5\,\text{mm}$.

Please do follow up in the comments if needing further clarification.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{array}\\
f\pi r^2 
&= r^2 \cos^{-1} \left(\frac{r-h}{r}\right)-(r-h)\sqrt{2rh-h^{2}}\\
&= r^2 \cos^{-1} \left(1-h/r\right)-r^2(1-h/r)\sqrt{2h/r-(h/r)^{2}}\\
&= r^2\left( \cos^{-1} \left(1-h/r\right)-(1-h/r)\sqrt{2h/r-(h/r)^{2}}\right)\\
f\pi
&=  \cos^{-1} \left(1-h/r\right)-(1-h/r)\sqrt{2h/r-(h/r)^{2}}\\
&=  \cos^{-1} \left(1-h/r\right)-(1-h/r)\sqrt{1-1+2h/r-(h/r)^{2}}\\
&=  \cos^{-1} \left(1-h/r\right)-(1-h/r)\sqrt{1-(1-h/r)^2}\\
&=  \cos^{-1}(u)-u\sqrt{1-u^2}
\qquad u=1-h/r\\
&=  \cos^{-1}(\cos(v))-\cos(v)\sqrt{1-\cos^2(v)}
\qquad u=\cos(v)\\
&=  v-\cos(v)\sin(v)\\
&=  v-\sin(2v)/2\\
&=  (2v-\sin(2v))/2\\
2f\pi
&=  2v-\sin(2v)\\
\end{array}
$

Solve this for $v$
in terms of $f$
(has to be done numerically),
then get
$u=\cos(v),
h=r(1-u)
$.

For small $v$,
$2v-\sin(2v)
\approx 2v-(2v-4v^3/3)
=4v^3/3
$
so,
for small $f$,

$\begin{array}\\
v 
&\approx (3f\pi/2)^{1/3}\\
u
&=\cos(v)\\
&\approx 1-v^2/2\\
&\approx 1-(3f\pi/2)^{2/3}/2\\
h
&\approx r(3f\pi/2)^{2/3}/2\\
\end{array}
$